# asyncio loop.run_until_complete not sleeping with asyncio.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

here is the code:

```
In [168]: async def myTask():
     ...:     await asyncio.sleep(2)
     ...:     print("processing task")

In [168]: async def generator():
     ...:     for i in range(5):
     ...:         asyncio.create_task(myTask())

In [168]: def abcd():
     ...:     t0=time.time()
     ...:     loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
     ...:     loop.run_until_complete(generator())
     ...:     t1=time.time()
     ...:     print(t1-t0)
```

Ideally calling abc() should sleep for around 10 seconds(as I have not awaited the `asyncio.create_task(myTask())`), but the function is getting completed in less than 0.1 secs.

```
In [167]: abcd()
processing task
processing task
processing task
processing task
processing task
0.0004038810729980469
```

Comment: You haven't awaited `myTask()`. If you try replacing `myTask()` with `asyncio.sleep(2)` directly, you'll get exactly the same behavior. Hmmm...

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, but in this case, no output should be printed. It's confusing.

Comment: Did you save the file beforehand? Try it again with the sample you posted. It seems to generate no additional output for me.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I am running it in python jupyter notebook

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/CylindricalSilkyLaboratory

Comment: thanks @MateenUlhaq. Seems like some issue in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Actually Jupyter notebook itself is an event loop. It might be the reason why you got output.

Answer (score 2):

If you try the following code, you will get output after around 2 seconds. Well, but we haven't awaited any tasks. The reason is that the Jupyter notebook itself is running in an event loop. So when you use the default event loop, it actually points to the Jupyter notebook's event loop.

```
import asyncio

async def myTask():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("processing task")

for i in range(5):
    asyncio.create_task(myTask())
```